# Spring (Error creating bean, No visible constructors) for Singleton class with private constructor

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have 4 singleton classes with private constructors 
and I'm trying to create bean property for all the 4 classes.

The main problem is, I'm able to create the bean for 3 classes
and these 3 classes have similar structure with a getInstance method and
a private constructor() (Singleton class) but the fourth and the last one
is throwing an exception (Exception message is pasted below)

Please find below the getInstance method, the private constructor
and the bean id declaration. Which is same across all the four bean declarations

But If I change the constructor from "Private" to "Public" then 
I dont get the error. Could anyone throw any light on what is happening? Since the other three classes have private constructors and they work perfectly fine

The getInstance() method

```
public static ApplicationConfiguration getInstance() throws IOException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InconsistentDataException {
        ApplicationConfiguration result = instance.get();
        if (result == null) {
            try {
                // Check again if already created
                result = instance.get();
                if (result == null) {
                    result = new ApplicationConfiguration();

                }
            } finally {
                // something here
            }
        } 
        return result;
    }
```

The private constructor

```
private ApplicationConfiguration() throws Exception {
        // call a method here
    }
```

The bean property declaration

```
<bean id="configManager" class="com.manager.ApplicationConfiguration" factory-method="getInstance" />

<bean id="configEnricher" class="com.enricher.ApplicationConfiguration" factory-method="getInstance" />

<bean id="configBussiness" class="com.validationservice.ApplicationConfiguration" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

The above three works

This bean property is throwing the error

```
<bean id="configEviction" class="com.evictionservice.ApplicationConfiguration" factory-method="getInstance" />
```

The Exception message

```
[#|2012-08-07 11:53:21,130|ERROR|RMI TCP Connection(226)-172.18.36.14|org.springframework.
web.context.ContextLoader||slodev-rhngp5.mblox.com|core-1|Context initialization failed|#]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'co
nfigEviction' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/camel-context.xml]: Initializat
ion of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigExcepti
on: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.evictionservice.ApplicationConfiguration]: 
Common causes of this problem include using
a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcepti
on: No visible constructors in class com.evictionservice.ApplicationConfiguration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.do
CreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.cr
eateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(Abstr
actBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingl
eton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Abstrac
tBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractB
eanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstant
iateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactor
yInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(Abstract
ApplicationContext.java:425)
:
```

Comment: Do you have any annotations on your `com.evictionservice.ApplicationConfiguration` class or any of its methods - say @Transaction etc.

Comment: Looks like there are 4 different classes here (all different packages). Does each ApplicationConfiguration extend a common interface? What does that look like? Do you have something in your spring context which is proxying on com.evictionservice classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not the bean creation itself (as you already noticed, that's not different from the other beans). The issue seems to be related to some AOP configuration that you're trying to use. If you want to create a proxy for that class, it cannot do it with CGLIB because the class cannot be subclassed (since it has a private constructor).

The only way to get around this (given your current design) is to create an interface that will be implemented  by the ApplicationConfiguration class and then create the proxy for that interface instead of proxy-ing the class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I'm not sure about the things that you are talking about which are AOP configuration, creating a proxy and interface. Already all four ApplicationConfiguration class has an interface and how do I create a proxy for the interface ? Where should I do a change and any hints on the change ?. Since the other three classes are working fine, I seriously don't understand what is happending.

Comment: Do you have anything like `<aop:...` or `<tx:...` in your application context or any `@Transactional` annotation applied ? If any of these aspects (and quite a few others) involve that class, the app context will try to create a proxy for it.

Comment: Yes,you are right, after going through my camel-context, I stumbled across this tag (<aop:config>) which is refering to the project (of the last singleton class). I removed the dependency and the bean is getting created without any issues. But I would like to know about the proxy that you are taking about and a good clear explanation about the AOP Configuration and these proxy stuff, any links ? I can search it online but its always good to hear from the experienced ones.

Comment: This section of the documentation explains the Spring AOP Proxies: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies